# Only some applications in my CommCare domain appear under "Web Apps"

Tags: commcare

When I select "Web Apps" in my project space on CommCare HQ, only some of my apps show up as an option. Can anyone help me determine why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a checkbox in the app settings to enable Web Apps for a particular app. Make sure that checkbox is selected, then make a build and star it for release and you should see your application.

Answer (score 0):

You might also check for display filters based on your active login. Not sure how that would affect display of the top-level app though...